# Symbole pour éviter la répétition d'un mot

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

Les équations fondamentales de la mécanique des milieux continus :

> 1. Bilan de la quantité de mouvement.
> 2. Bilan du moment cinétique.
> 3. Bilan de masse.
> 4. Bilan d'énergie.

Est-il possible d'éviter l'écriture répétée du mot bilan ? Si oui, avec quel symbole ? E.g. la construction

> 1. Bilan de la quantité de mouvement.
> 2. *>>* du moment cinétique.
> 3. *>>*  de masse.
> 4. *>>*  d'énergie.

a-t-elle du sens en français ?

Comment: Il y a bien le symbole qui en unicode s'appelle *ditto mark* « 〃» , que l'on aperçoit parfois, mais c'est quand même assez rare de le rencontrer.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est noté, merci !

Comment: C'est quoi cette volonté d'éviter une répétition ? Tu fais de la littérature maintenant ? => Soit le terme de *bilan* a son importance et alors **tu l'écris** et le répètes, soit il n'en a pas et alors... tu le vire de partout!. (Et à mon opinion, ici... il en a!)

Comment: @aCOSwt Imagine que tu écris sur le tableau ou bien tu prépares une diapo (niveau post-bac). Dans ma langue maternelle (grec) ce truc pour tels emplois est fréquent et non bizarre. Je me demandais s'il existe en français. C'est tout:-)!

Comment: Tableau / diapo ou pas, la vraie (et seule) question subsiste. Il est important ou pas ce terme de *bilan* ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, c'est bien important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a le « [point ditto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark) », symbole assez bien établi pour les langues occidentales.

Selon Wikipédia, le caractère *"* transforme en son équivalent *»* dans un contexte français, comme tu l'as prévu. Mais selon les commentaires, on peut aussi trouver *"* ou *//*, probablement dû à la difficulté de taper les guillemets traditionnels.

Il est aussi à noter que la largeur du symbole doit être l'équivalent de celle du mot ainsi remplacé afin d'assurer l'alignement :

> 1. Bilan de la quantité de mouvement.
> 2. »    du moment cinétique.
> 3. ...

Ce n'est pas tous les jours que je le rencontre, au moins parmi ceux de mon âge, mais ayant grandi pendant les années 90, on l'a appris des professeurs en école élémentaire, donc peut-être que c'est pas si démodé que ça. :)

En tout cas, une autre solution à considérer est de structurer la phrase de sorte que la répétition soit implicite :

> Bilans :
>
> 1. de la quantité de mouvement ;
> 2. du moment cinétique ;
> 3. ...

Comment: Je ne crois pas que ce symbole se transforme comme les guillemets en français. Je n'ai jamais vu » ainsi utilisé, seulement ”. On doit aussi songer à aligner le début des mots qui suivent le mot répété, marqué ”.

Comment: J'ai cherché et ai trouvé que *Le Bon usage*  recommende les guillemets français, en effet, pour cet usage aussi. Néanmoins, il y est bien question de l’alignement du mot suivant.

Comment: Je crois avoir déjà vu le guillemet français dans l'ancien système d'impression, pendant une période que je ne saurais définir précisément (peut être car le caractère n'était pas disponible facilement?). Je crois qu'on ne le trouve plus (sous aucune forme) dans les publications récentes. Mais dans les rares cas ou on l'écrit à la main le symbole est normalement constitué de deux traits obliques (c'est un symbole qui est en fait bien distinct des guillemets anglais courbés).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je le connais principalement moi-même pour l'avoir écrit à la main, avoir vu de nombreux professeurs l'écrire au tableau et mes parents et grand-parents me définir un peu mieux en quelles circonstances et de quelle manière on utilise cet artifice. Tous utilisaient les guillemets anglais. Mais je viens du Canada, et nos coutumes peuvent avoir été longtemps distinctes de celles d'Europe.